# How can I cache a .swf file in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I'm working on a page that allows a user to toggle between different (fairly large) swf files.

The first swf object loads on page load, and when the user clicks to view another, the first is set to display:none, so the second can cover the whole page.

My problem is that when the user clicks back to the first, it undergoes the same lengthy loading process it did on page load.

I assumed that caching the swf objects in the DOM and simply toggling their visibility would make it possible for the the user to toggle back and forth quickly, without the delay, while maintaining state.

The kicker is that this works in Internet Explorer, but none of the other browsers.

Am I fighting an unwinnable battle? Has any one successfully cached swf files and maintained their state in the DOM?

Comment: I've always had to add a something random or a timestamp not to have a player cached. Does your path to the swf add anything like that? Or maybe the page has a no-cache directive?

Comment: No, we don't add anything to path... if I'm just toggling the visibility of the objects--not requesting new ones-- why would the browser try and give me a cached version?

Comment: when you say "clicks back", are you talking about an html link/button, or the actual browser back button?

Comment: It's clicking a link on the page to another route (doesn't reload the page).